# Typescript await a void function execution, which has a subscribe method inside

Tags: javascript, typescript

The code below is taken from angular typescript components!

I have a block of code like this

```
function test(){
    this.showLoadingScreen();
    this.service.getData();
    this.hideLoadingScreen();
}
```

The `getData()` Method has a subscribe inside it, which is making a http request. E.g

```
function getData(){
    this.someService.performHttpRequest().subscribe( (data) => {...});
}
```

The problem is that the loading screen is dismissed before the actual result comes from the server. How can I await the result of `getData()` method inside the `test()` method?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using `axios`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not awaiting the getData() function to complete.
So, make it a Promise as well, and wait for that one.

```js
function getData(){
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) =>
            this.someService.performHttpRequest().subscribe((data) => { resolve(data); })
    );
// or shorter: ....subscribe(resolve);
}
```

and use it with

```js
await this.service.getData();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can not modify the getData() method. Is it possible to encapsulate it in another method?